# Send message to SQL Server message queue from C# Win CE

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-ce, message-queue

I have a queue called log_line_queue in database cja on SQL Server ITSERVER.

I have a C# Win CE application running on a mobile device. I want to send a message from this application to log_line_queue.

This is my code so far:

```
var myQueue = new System.Messaging.MessageQueue("FormatName:Direct=OS:itserver\\private$\\dbo.cja.log_line_queue");

myQueue.Send("My Message Data.", MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
```

It results in

```
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: Message Queue service is not available.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_WriteHandle()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS properties, IntPtr transaction)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(Object obj, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Send(Object obj, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
   at cjaTest1.MessageQueue.FrmSendToQueue.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog(IntPtr hwnModal)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at cjaTest1.FrmMainForm.button9_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
   at cjaTest1.Program.Main()
```

I'm sure I'm doing many things wrong. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Messaging.MessageQueue` is used to interact with [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `A queue called log_line_queue in database cja on SQL Server ITSERVER` is either a table or a Service Broker Queue. This is Apples and Oranges, MSMQ has nothing to do with SQL Server. To send messages to a SQL Server queue you must use the [SEND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188407.aspx) T-SQL verb, and you must be connected to a SQL Server instance.

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot.